# How to prevent Excel import in SSIS package when there is no file to process?

Tags: excel, datetime, ssis, package

I have an SSIS package that imports Excel files. Inside the package, I have a Script task that checks whether the Excel file exists or not before executing the Excel import process.

I am unable to execute the package when the Excel file doesn't exist because of the `AcquireConnection` error.

How can I prevent the package from executing when there is no Excel file available for import?

Comment: If you check if the file exists first, how can there be an error afterwards?

Comment: @Siva, that might be the case, good call!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform the following steps to avoid the package from failing.

- Set the `ValidateExternalMetadata` property on the *Excel Source* to `False`.
- Set the `DelayValidation` property on the *Excel Connection* to `True`.

The package validation phase happens first even before your Script task can execute. If the Excel file, doesn't exist then the package validation phase will fail. Setting the above property values will delay the validation and you can check if the first exist or not in your script task. If the file doesn't exist, you can abort the package execution.

Comment: I try it but doesn't work. First I have try to change "DelayValidation". I have already write my scrip to know if file exit or not to execute the task or not.. but juste i don't want package's validation phase try to test if file exist

Comment: OK i found !! I need to put DelayValidation to TRUE on the package too